# Error: page11 line 7, column 8: The end-tag for element type "a" must end with a '>' delimiter hitting this error

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true" tabStyle="account"> 
  <style>activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white;background-image:none} inactiveTab {background-color: lightgrey; color:black;background-image:none}
  </style> 
   <apex:tabPanelswitchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">   
   <apex:tablabel="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails">
   <apex:detailrelatedList="false" title="true"/> 
    </apex:tab>                         
     <apex:tablabel="Contacts" name="Contacts" id="tabContact">     
      <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="contacts" />  
       </apex:tab> 
        <apex:tablabel="Opportunities" name="Opportunities" id="tabOpp">  
       <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="opportunities" /> 
      </apex:tab> 
     <apex:tablabel="Open Activities" name="OpenActivities" id="tabOpenAct">                    
     <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="OpenActivities"/>        
     </apex:tab> 
   <apex:tablabel="Notes and Attachments" name="NotesAndAttachments" id="tabNoteAtt">   
  <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="NotesAndAttachments"/>  
 </apex:tab> 
</apex:tabPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Normally, an error message as the title and a block of code doesn't make for a very good question. A good thing to remember is that people can't read your mind, so it's a good idea to assume that nobody else knows anything (outside of general experience with Salesforce) _unless you explicitly tell us_. It looks like Pranay was able to hit the nail on the head this time, but including the source of your code (if you got it from a blog) would have been helpful here.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as `apex:tablabel` ,`apex:tabPanelswitchType` and `apex:detailrelatedList`.

The place from where you copied this , has messed up formating and spaces.

If you format it properly, it works

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true" tabStyle="account"> 
  <style>activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white;background-image:none} inactiveTab {background-color: lightgrey; color:black;background-image:none}
  </style> 

   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">   
       <apex:tab label="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails">
           <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="true"/> 
       </apex:tab>     

       <apex:tab label="Contacts" name="Contacts" id="tabContact">     
           <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="contacts" />  
       </apex:tab> 


       <apex:tab label="Opportunities" name="Opportunities" id="tabOpp">  
           <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="opportunities" /> 
       </apex:tab> 

       <apex:tab label="Open Activities" name="OpenActivities" id="tabOpenAct">                    
           <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="OpenActivities"/>        
       </apex:tab> 

       <apex:tab label="Notes and Attachments" name="NotesAndAttachments" id="tabNoteAtt">   
           <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="NotesAndAttachments"/>  
       </apex:tab> 

    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```